# How to write a lambda function for keras layers as layer1 * layer2 = product(layer1 * layer2)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

Input shape(None,75) ,next layer(Hidden layer 1) shape is (75,3), and next layer(Hidden layer 2) shape is (3,1).For the last layer, the output must be calculated as ( (H21*w1)*(H22*w2)*(H23*w3)), where H21,H22,H23 will be the outcome of Hidden layer 2, and w1,w2,w3 will be constant weight which are not trainable. So how to write a lambda function for the above outcome

Answer (score 0):

first for structure like this dont use the sequential model, try to use the funtional model, by importing the input, the layers you need and the model just like this:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import Dense

# Define the input
visible = Input(shape=(2,))  

# Connecting layers
hidden = Dense(2)(visible)  

# Create the model
model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=hidden)
```

And for the Lambda this is how you do it, you take the the two layers

```
cross1 = Lambda(product, output_shape=....)([Layer1,Layer2])
```

where product:

```
def product(x):
       return x[0] * x[1]
```

Comment: keras_model = Sequential()
keras_model.add(Dense(75, input_dim=75,activation='tanh',name="layer1" ))
keras_model.add(Dense(3 ,activation='tanh',name="layer2" ))
keras_model.add(Dense(1,name="layer3"))
cross1=keras_model.add(Lambda(lambda x:product,output_shape=(1,1)))([layer2,layer3])
print(cross1)        

showing error NameError: name 'layer2' is not defined

Comment: the line of code i gave u doesnt work with the sequantial function to create a model. In fact, there's two methods to create a model, one is with the squential model or like you did the second is called the functional model is like the example i gave above. so try to learn about the functional model. coz it the right way to make an complexe architecture.

Comment: thankyou for your explanation sir...
# Define the input
visible = Input(shape=(75,))


hidden1 = Dense(75,activation='sigmoid' )(visible)  
hidden2 = Dense(3,activation='relu',trainable=False )(hidden1)  
hidden3 = Dense(1,)(hidden2)  

net = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=hidden3)
cross1 = Lambda(product, output_shape=(1,1))([hidden2,hidden3])
net.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
net.fit(X_train, Y_train,epochs=5000,batch_size=32)
ynew = net.predict(X_test)     
   
is it correct...but how to give constant weights to hidden layer3